# Should Singleton pattern be used for Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, singleton, media-player

I am a newbie to Android and currently learning the Android SDK.

I am writing a very simple application that will just play various sounds upon interacting with widgets. I am using MediaPlayer to playback the sounds.

My question is should i use singleton pattern for MediaPlayer? I want just one object of MediaPlayer to be shared, but the confusion comes from the following link

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

which says that:

> It is also recommended that once a MediaPlayer object is no longer
>   being used, call release() immediately so that resources used by the
>   internal player engine associated with the MediaPlayer object can be
>   released immediately. Resource may include singleton resources such as
>   hardware acceleration components and failure to call release() may
>   cause subsequent instances of MediaPlayer objects to fallback to
>   software implementations or fail altogether.

I don't want to run MediaPlayer as service for now.

So what should i do? Should I use the Singleton Pattern for MediaPlayer?

Great Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advisable , as you can see from the extract, to keep an object of MediaPlayer as a singleton. Mainly because valuable resources such as hardware could be kept locked as long as you have a media player object in **any of the states other than the END state**. Also when you call release(), the object cannot be *reused.* You would need a new instance.
I think the android team wants the developers to create objects when needed and release it when done.