# Managing MediaPlayer instance in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing and application which, among other functionalities, is intended to play audio tracks. There is a navigation drawer Activity which starts up a fragment when drawer menu option is clicked. There are two fragments which play role in "media player" functionality:

- TracksListFragment (ListView with song titles)
- PlayerFragment (audio player)

In order to play a song, user selects one of the songs inside TracksListFragment and then PlayerFragment opens up to play that particular song.

At this point I'm able to play a song, pause it and resume. If I pause a song and try to play another song it also works fine. My setup fails when there is a song being played at the moment and I try to play different one: both tracks play simultaneously. I avoided using singleton approach as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870656/should-singleton-pattern-be-used-for-android-mediaplayer)

What I have tried so far:

- unsetting MediaPlayer if it's object already exists
- switching from `MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();` to `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), Uri.parse(songPath));`

Can someone explain why new MediaPlayer objects are being created even though I try to get rid of existing ones, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my Fragment class for PlayerFragment:

```
    public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment {

    public String currentTrack;
    private TextView currentTrackText;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private ImageButton trackButtonPlayPause;
    private Integer length;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_player, container, false);

        currentTrackText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(trackTitleText);
        trackButtonPlayPause = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trackButtonPlayPause);

        MenuActivity activity = (MenuActivity) getActivity();
        String currentTrack = activity.getTrackInfoToBePlayed();
        String currentPath = activity.getTrackPathToBePlayed();

        currentTrackText.setText(currentTrack);

        playSong(currentPath);


        // Register Button Click event
        trackButtonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(isPlaybackOn() == true){
                    Log.e("PLAYER ---> ", "Song playing->pause");

                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    trackButtonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_track_play);
                    length=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                }else{
                    Log.e("PLAYER ---> ", "Song not playing->resume");
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
                    trackButtonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public void  playSong(String songPath){
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songPath);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }else{
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songPath);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isPlaybackOn(){
        AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if(manager.isMusicActive())
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void stopSong(){
        // to be implemented
    }

}
```

TracksListFragment:

```
public class TracksListFragment extends Fragment {
    private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;
    private ArrayList<Song> songList;
    private ExpandableListView songView;

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_moja_muzyka, container, false);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tracks);

        // query songs
        songView = (ExpandableListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tracks);
        songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        getSongList();


        SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(rootView.getContext(), songList,listDataHeader,listDataChild);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);


        // Listview Group click listener
        songView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                 "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });


        // Listview Group expanded listener
        songView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                // hide all groups but clicked
                if (lastExpandedPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                    expListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
                }
                lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;



            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        songView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {


            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        songView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                return false;
            }
        });



        return rootView;

    }

    public void getSongList() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        Integer audioCounter = -1;

        ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3");
        String sel = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
        String[] selExtARGS = new String[]{fileExtension};
        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor songCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, sel, selExtARGS, null);


        if(songCursor!=null && songCursor.moveToFirst()){
            //get columns

            int titleColumn = songCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = songCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = songCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int albumColumn = songCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
            int mimeColumn = songCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE);
            int fullpathColumn = songCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

            //add songs to list

            do {
                audioCounter++;
                long thisId = songCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = songCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = songCursor.getString(artistColumn) ;
                String thisAlbum = songCursor.getString(albumColumn);
                String thisPath = songCursor.getString(fullpathColumn);
                if(thisArtist.toLowerCase().contains("unknown")){
                    thisArtist = getResources().getString(R.string.textSongNoArtistAvailable);
                }
                if(thisAlbum.toLowerCase().contains("music")){
                    thisAlbum = getResources().getString(R.string.textSongNoAlbumAvailable);
                }
                String thisMime = songCursor.getString(mimeColumn);

                listDataHeader.add(thisTitle);
                List<String> songDetails = new ArrayList<String>();
                songDetails.add(thisTitle);
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(audioCounter), songDetails);

                songList.add(new Song(thisPath,thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisAlbum));
            }
            while (songCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: "In order to play a song, user selects one of the songs inside TracksListFragment and then PlayerFragment opens up to play that particular song." - can you show the code for this part?

Comment: @T.S certainly, code added

Comment: Have you tried setRetainInstance(true) to your  PlayerFragment so it won't be recreated?